# System.setClipBoard not work on browser

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried to copy a text to clipboard with As3, when I run it on Flash Player it works, but if I include it in a page and I upload it, it doesn' t work.

The code:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendTextFromJS", receiveTextFromJS);

function receiveTextFromJS(t:String):void {
    System.setClipboard(t);
}
```

Flash receives the text from JavaScript, but it not insert it in the ClipBoard. Someone knows why?

Comment: Sounds like you might be running into some sort of security error possibly.  I've done a fair amount of work using AS3 and the clipboard so I know how problematic it can be, not to mention the clipboard itself in windows is deceptively simple.  You may want to search around for a clipboard viewer application, I found one at some point that shows all the values and the formats stored in the system clipboard.  Beyond that be sure you're using the debug flash player version, potentially investigate the allowDomain attribute in the Embed/Object code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, Security. FP 10 later securiy changes.

read this article: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes.html#head31

I recommend. implements using a [Clipboard Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html)